# django custom external libraries

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to add some Python scripts for usage in my project. I am using django, python27, apache, mysql, mod_wsgi. The scripts can be ran by themselves outside of Django. And they do. However, I want to add them to my django project for usage throughout my project. I added sys.path.append('path to my scripts') to my settings.py file. However, when I do an "from scripts import *" in a django view I get an import error saying the module does not exist. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an `__init__.py` file into your scripts folder to make the folder a python package?  That file differentiates a regular folder from a python package (among other things).

See python docs for more info:  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Yep I did. And I ended up just adding it as a module like all the others. If people want to reuse them they will have to import them as a module into their projects as well.